# how Spring calls Argumented Constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i have this class

```
@Component 
public class Workflow{
```

with default and argument constructor
something like this

```
public Workflow(GraphModel graph, JSONObject state, String md5Hash)
            throws InvalidGraphException {
        this(graph);
        this.setState(state);
        this.setMd5Hash(md5Hash);
    }
```

now when i use

```
@Autowired
Workflow workflow;
```

it works just fine
 but i want to call constructor with arguments .,how can i achieve this?

**Please note** i tried creating bean like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xyz.abc.*")
public class BlueBerryBeansConfiguration {
    @Bean
public Workflow getWorkflow(GraphModel graph, JSONObject getJson,
        String getmd5) throws InvalidGraphException {
    return new Workflow(graph, getJson, getmd5);
}



@Bean
public JSONObject getJson() {
    return new JSONObject();
}

@Bean
public String getmd5() {
    return new String();
}

}
```

and in Workflow constructor

```
@Autowired
    public Workflow(GraphModel graph, JSONObject state, String md5Hash)
            throws InvalidGraphException {
        this(graph);
        this.setState(state);
        this.setMd5Hash(md5Hash);
    }

    public Workflow(GraphModel graph) throws InvalidGraphException {
        this.setUnpackedGraph(graph);
    }
```

i am getting null pointer,exception makes sense to me but how can i resolve it >?

Please provide your valuable feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor should do it. If it doesn't work, try removing the default constructor if you have one.

Comment: please see my description once again since i have made some changes,

Comment: Either samples that you have provided later (using @Autowired and @Bean) looks right. Maybe looking at the full code would he helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed my approach because what i have learned is

```
  @Bean
public Workflow getWorkflow(GraphModel graph, JSONObject getJson,
        String getmd5) throws InvalidGraphException {
    return new Workflow(graph, getJson, getmd5);
}
```

as per above code i need to declare GraphModel, JSONObject  and getmd5 as beans as well which raises **another issue as GraphModel and JSONObject have non no argument constructors**  so i have to declare them as beans as well so it will form kind of complicated loop.

So if your  case is also like mine then it is better to call

```
  @Autowired
Workflow workflow;
```

and then explicitly setting the graph and json objects. it is not 100 % answer but it is work around .i hope one day i will find the right solution.
And if you are reading this and think otherwise and have better solution then please comment.